# Perfectum with multiple verbs

Tags: word-order, perfect-tense

I know, that in `perfectum sentence` containing modal verb, the order of words looks something like this :

```
Ich habe nach Hause gehen wollen
```

My question is, how do I order words in perfectum sentence, when it contains multiple verbs, but none of them is modal ? Is it the same case as with modal verbs ? Something like :

```
Ich habe deutsch lernen beginnen
```

Comment: It's *Ich habe Deutsch zu lernen begonnen* -- or, more common: *Ich habe begonnen, Deutsch zu lernen*

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: Side note: _ich habe Deutsch lernen begonnen_ can be acceptable in colloquial speech, but not in written form.

Answer (score 3):

Note that we have to distinguish between **monoclausal** and **multiclausal** structures. Monoclausal structures occur with:

- temporal auxiliaries (*haben*, *sein* plus past participle; *werden* plus infinitive)
- modals (modal verbs plus infinitive)
- passive auxiliaries (for instance *werden* plus past participle)
- and combinations thereof.

In **monoclausal** structures, the order at the end is as follows:

> als das Haus **gebaut<sub>3</sub> worden<sub>2</sub> ist<sub>1</sub>**

In order to talk about order, it is useful to give each verb a **rank**, starting with the finite verb at rank 1. In the above example, the perfect auxiliary *ist* (rank 1) governs the passive auxiliary *worden* (rank 2), which governs the past participle *gebaut* (rank 3). Yet the order is exactly the opposite: 3-2-1, i.e. **in monoclausal structures the order is descending**.

Some additional examples:

> ob man das Problem **lösen<sub>3</sub> können<sub>2</sub> wird<sub>1</sub>**
> dass die Steuern **gesenkt<sub>3</sub> werden<sub>2</sub> müssen<sub>1</sub>**

However, there are also **multiclausal** structures, where the embedded clauses are called **Infinitivkonstruktionen**. These always involve *zu*-infinitives. The hallmark of these structures is that the lowest ranked verb, together with all its dependents, can occur in the *Nachfeld* (*extraposed*). In the following examples, I have used a vertical bar | to indicate where one clause ends and the other one starts.

> seit ich begonnen<sub>2</sub> habe<sub>1</sub> | **Deutsch zu lernen<sub>3</sub>**
> obwohl er versprochen<sub>2</sub> hat<sub>1</sub> | **das Problem zu lösen<sub>3</sub>**

In contrast to the auxiliaries involved in monoclausal structures, verbs allowing *Infinitivkonstruktionen* usually introduce some kind of lexical meaning: *anfangen* etc.; *versprechen*, *befehlen*, *bitten* etc.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is at a level at which he cannot with certainty tell what that mean applied to his example.

Comment: Typical show off answer - hardly understandable even for native speakers, explaining nothing really, mildly interesting for linguists at most. The "lowest ranked verb"? Good luck to any learner trying to make sense of that explanation.

Comment: @Olafant Thank you for the kind words.

Comment: @DavidVogt Sorry, but I think it's really frustrating and even more confusing for someone who is trying to learn German.

Comment: @Olafant I see two options: (i) constructive criticism, (ii) writing another answer.

Comment: @DavidVogt, I agree.